# How Byte data be converted to bits and again converted back to Byte?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

1 Byte = 8 bits.
I have to work on 120 bits. So 15 Byte. 
This 120 bits will be in the form of 00010101000000............
So each 8 bit that is 00010101 is 1 Byte. 
So I want do some kind of modification operation on that and then add up all the Bytes back. Will the Bytes be stored in an Byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a large number of bits you could use BitSet.  You can use byte[] or long[] it doesn't matter as they are all made up of bits in the end. Using a byte[] won't make the object any smaller than a long[] as most JVMs use 8-byte boundaries for objects. A long[] is more efficent for some operations.

Comment: +1 because when you have a set of bits using a `BitSet` is a straight match

Answer (score 0):

Byte array is a good idea. But it is up to you how to store them...

Answer (score 0):

Split the stream in 8 bit chunks and use Byte.valueOf(String, int) for each chunk.

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you how you will store the bytes.
You can modify bytes using bits operations like & and |.
For ex.:

```
x |= 2;
```